# Can I implement park/unpark methods in pure Java?

Tags: java, synchronization, jvm, concurrent-programming

I know LockSupport is part of the JDK, but I am wondering if the implementation below is semantically correct. Observe that Object.wait can deal with the problem of thread's interrupt. My question is not regarding performance; however, I will appreciate any suggestion to improve my solution as long as your solution only uses basic construction like wait, notify and synchronized.

Thanks a lot.

```
final class LockSupport {
    static void park(long time) {
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        if (th instanceof MyThread) {
            MyThread h = (MyThread)th;
            synchronized (h.obj) {
                if (h.permit) {
                    h.permit = false;
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    h.obj.wait(time);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }

    static void unpark(MyThread h) {
        synchronized (h.obj) {
            h.permit = true;
            h.obj.notify();
        }
    }
}

abstract class MyThread extends Thread {
    public Object obj = new Object();
    public boolean permit = true;
}
```

Comment: You should wait in a loop to deal with spurious wakeups.

Comment: No, the documentation states that park may return because of spurious condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial permit should be false.

When an interrupt is caught, you need to re-interrupt the current thread

```
 catch (InterruptedException e) { th.interrupt(); }
```

because if `park()` returns due to interrupt, the interrupt status should be set (see javadoc example)

After `wait()` completes, normally or abruptly due to interrupt, consume the permit.

In `unpark()`, if permit is already true, there's no need to notify.

Comment: You are right; however, the behaviour is not equal to the OpenJDK implementation in both, your and my solution.